# How to set / get a property of a extended class?

Tags: javascript, class

I have a template class:

```js
class Person {
    constructor(info) {
        this.name = info.name;
        this.age = info.age;
    }
    talk() {
        return `${this.name} talked.`;
    }

}
module.exports = Person;
```

And I have another file that I run:

```js
var Person = require('./Person')
class Me extends Person{
     constructor() {
          super({
          name: 'Me',
          age: 18
          })
     }
}
```

How do I get or set the name if I want to retrieve it again? And am I setting or getting it correctly? In `class Person`, `constructor(info)`, `info` is supposed to be an object.

**What I've tried:**

```js
var Person = require('./Person')
class Me extends Person{
     constructor(info) {
          super(info);
          this.name = 'Name'; //still does "undefined?"
     }
}
```

I even tried changing my `Person` class.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    talk() {
        return `${this.name} talked.`;
    }

}
module.exports = Person;
```

Which still returns `undefined` as `this.name`

How do I get the class properties like `name` or `age` from `class Me` so they return things like `name = Me` and `age = 18`?

Comment: that's because those members are not on the prototype. Class.name just returns the name of the class, it is inherited from function. Just use `const o = new MyClass;` console.log(o.name)`. That said, I don't think you want classes at all for this kind of thing

Comment: "var Me = new Person({name: 'Me'})", `Me` is defined as subClass and then you define it as instance of the Person class, you can't do that!!!, and I don't know why do you want to set a name but you can do that `Me.prototype.name = "Your Name"`

Comment: The property `name` (not the function/class name) shows up as undefined if I use `class ... extends Person`. If I use `new Person`, I can get the name.

Comment: Please show us how you are calling `talk` on the `Me` instance.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, it was not clear, where exactly the properties should be "get or set" - in `Me` class or when working with its instance.

Please, check if this snippet works for you.

```js
class Person {
  constructor(info) {
    this.name = info.name;
    this.age = info.age;
  }

  talk() {
    return `${this.name} talked.`;
  }
}

class Me extends Person{
  constructor(info) {
    super(info);
  }
}

const me = new Me({ name: 'John', age: 19 });

console.log(me);
console.log(me.name);
console.log(me.age);
console.log(me.talk());

me.name = 'Jerry';
console.log(me);
console.log(me.name);
console.log(me.age);
console.log(me.talk());
```